# How to prevent third-party plugin chunk compiles every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-2

I have a common file `common.js` requires a  jQuery plugin as an async chunk.

```
function init($elm) {
  // loaded select2 lib if needed
  if (!$.fn.select2) {
    require.ensure([], function () {
      require('./path/to/select2.js');
      $elm.select2();
    }, 'select');
    return $elm;
  }

  $elm.select2();
  return $elm;
}

if ($('.js-select2').length) {
    init($('.js-select2'));
}
```

and webpack can generate a `chunk.common.js` and `chunk.select.js` and it will load `chunk.common.js` then load `chunk.select.js` if needed.

But my problem is every I edit `base.js`, both `chunk.common.js` and `chunk.select.js` compiles. How can I make `chunk.select.js` as a common chunk that shouldn't compiles every time.

My webpack config like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    common: './common.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: 'dist/js/',
    publicPath: 'js/',
    filename: 'chunk-[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'lib/chunk-[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```